# How do I hook paper-tabs and core-animated-pages together?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I've been going over [Rob Dudson's I/O talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKrYfrAzqFA) (at 27:00) and trying to use [core-animated-pages](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages) with paper-tabs.

When I click the tab, I would like some respective content to be shown, with the animation.

I tried to follow Rob's approach of using the designer, but somehow I do not get the 'selected' property in the properties panel.
The polymer docs cover tabs and animated-pages separately, so I don't know how I can get them to work together.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/Polymer/designer/issues/63) in the [currently deployed designer tool](http://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/) that prevents certain bindable attributes from being displayed in the properties pane. It has been fixed in [master](https://github.com/Polymer/inspector-elements/commit/99079030362713c6a5e36f6c9c0f3132889cdfa2#diff-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e), so the next time the Polymer team deploys the tool, it should fix your problem.

In the meantime, you could install the tool using `bower install Polymer/designer#master` to get the fixed version locally.

Comment: Cool. :) If not for designer, is there any other way I can hook them together?

Comment: Yup! Just switch to the code view in the designer (the `<>` button), find the nodes you want to bind, and set one's selected property to the selected property of the other: `<core-animated-pages selected="{{ $.paper_tabs.selected }}">`, assuming the ID of your paper-tabs element is `paper_tabs`.

Answer (score 1):

`core-animated-pages` works with `div` tags. Then just add `addEventListener` to select the page.

Here is a working example (jsfiddle): [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxmka822/6/).